# Replace pom version using sed in Jenkinsfile

Tags: linux, unix, jenkins, sed

I have a variable `myStr`that contains the following value:

```
    "app": {
    "services": {
      "app": [{
          "groupID": "com.mycompany",
          "artifactId": "myapp-versions",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        {
          "groupID": "com.mycompany.xyz",
          "artifactId": "car-stats",
          "version": "1.0-master"
        },

        {
          "groupID": "com.mycompany.service",
          "artifactId": "my-differential-service",
          "version": "1.0.0-master"
        }

    ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to replace the version of only `my-differential-service` artifactId to `NEW_VERSION`.

I tried using sed command on `myStr` variable but couldn't succeed as I am not much familiar with this command.

Can anyone please guide me on how should I proceed to achieve this?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: yes!! myStr is a bash variable

Comment: @AkhilPrajapati: Can you install new tools in your Jenkins executors? You need to download and install `jq` for syntactically parsing JSON text

Comment: @Inian I am not authorized for installing new tools in Jenkins.

Comment: I can still try. Can you please provide the jq based solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you need `sed` for parsing this, look for the support of the option `-z` in your `sed`. This option ignores the special meaning of `\n`.
When you know that version is the first field after the artifactId you can try

```
new_version=1.0.1 # avoid uppercase variable names
echo "$myStr" | 
   sed -rz 's/("my-differential-service",[^:]*: ")[^"]*/\1'"${new_version}"'/'
```

When the order of fields can change, you might want to ask for `jq` in Jenkins or try `awk`.
When you want to use `sed` but don't have the `-z` option, you can translate first:

```
echo "$myStr" | tr '\n' '\r' | sed -r 's/..../' | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `jq` is available, congrats! and please try the following:

```
echo "{ $myStr }" | jq '(.app.services.app[] | select(.artifactId == "my-differential-service") | .version) = "NEW_VERSION"'
```

which yields:

```
{
  "app": {
    "services": {
      "app": [
        {
          "groupID": "com.mycompany",
          "artifactId": "myapp-versions",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        {
          "groupID": "com.mycompany.xyz",
          "artifactId": "car-stats",
          "version": "1.0-master"
        },
        {
          "groupID": "com.mycompany.service",
          "artifactId": "my-differential-service",
          "version": "NEW_VERSION"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you do not need the outermost curly braces, please remove them by bash's parameter expansion or something similar.

As a fallback, you can say with `sed`:

```
echo "$myStr" | sed '
:l
N
$!b l
s/\("my-differential-service"[^"]*"version": *\)"[^"]*"/\1"NEW_VERSION"/g'
```

Hope this helps.